# Cauchy integration theorem proof

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, curves

My textbook reports the following result:

Given $f\colon A \subseteq \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ holomorphic in the open simply connected set $A$, and given $\gamma\colon [a,b] \to A$ a simple closed and piecewise regular curve in $A$, then $\int_{\gamma} f(z)\,\text{d}z=0$.

Then, my textbook states that every closed piecewise regular curve is given by the union of a finite number of simple closed curves and simple open (namely non closed) curves.

Using the last fact, it expands the previous result to closed and piecewise regular curves (the relevant fact now is that there is no longer the "simple" condition).

I got it all, but I was wondering if exists a nice (and fast) manner of rigorously showing that every closed piecewise regular curve is given by the union of a finite number of simple closed curves and simple open curves.

Sorry for my english and thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: Elementi di analisi complessa, Carlo Presilla. He is an italian author. I have no idea if there exists an english version.

Comment: However maybe I have used too many words for my question. My question is simply: is it true that every generic closed curve is given by the union of a finite number of simple closed curves and simple unclosed curves? And if it is true, is there a simple way to prove it? Or it's like with Jordan curve theorem (namely, simple thesis, difficult proof)? Thank you.

Comment: You could [edit] your question accordingly if you want.

Comment: I prefer showing the reason that lead me to this question. Maybe someone could give me another way to prove this Cauchy result. Thank you just the same.